Could it make sense to think of 0, -1, and i as overloaded unary operators rather than numbers?
This thought occurred to me and I was wondering if anyone had explored it.
For example, -x = (-1)*x. We could (choosing arbitrary symbols) rewrite this as @(x), meaning rotate 180 degrees in the complex plane. Likewise i*x could be #(x), meaning rotate 90 degrees. Finally, 0*x could be written as &(x), which means set to the origin.
A notation like that has some intuitive appeal to me since we can't have -5 apples, x/0 and x/+ are both undefined, and so on. In general these objects seem to fall somewhere between operators and numbers. Perhaps infinity is another example.
Is this just a crazy thought? Or could the current practice be only a cultural artifact, with whatever advantages/disadvantages that entails?

Could you do it? Sure. Better question: what would be the practical use in doing so?

@PrincessEev If you look at the history there was resistance to treating them as numbers and their "idiosyncratic" behaviors also cause consternation in current students. So perhaps it would provide a more intuitive basis with fewer seemingly arbitrary rules. Also, perhaps there are unsolved problems that become non-issues when thinking of it this way.

We also do use the concept of a "negative" number of objects intuitively all the time. For instance, if we have a crate of 50 apples and then we eat one, then the crate  is "short" by one apple.

@Livid On the contrary. Thinking, for example, about complex numbers as no-numbers or "imaginary" numbers caused delays in the progress of complex numbers. Once the complex numbers were formally constructed and generally accepted it was easier to understand them and develop a deep theory. The same happened with the negative numbers.

For every number $x$, multiplication by $x$ is a unary operator.

@jjagmath Afaik, the current notation was devised before the concept of the complex plane. Perhaps it is more historical accident than the ideal. To the others, thanks. But these specific numbers clearly have special properties not shared by the others.

@Livid Yes, the notation was devised before, but the important advances in the theory that lead to deep and insightful theorems came after the demystification of the numbers.

@jjagmath To be clear, I am not claiming this notation (or similar) would be easier to work with. But I am not assuming the current way is best just because that is what we grew up with either. The question is whether it obviously doesn't work or if people have explored the advantages/disadvantages of this other way of looking at it.

Yes, and in fact I claim this is actually the best way to think about them!
When we say, for example, that something has length $\ell$, this $\ell$ is not a number. To actually measure a length you have to pick units so you can say this length is $\ell = 3 \text{ meters}$ or whatever else. But what does this really mean? It means that to measure lengths you have to pick a reference length (which in the case of the meter used to be a specific physical bar of platinum in France) and then measure other lengths relative to that length.
When we say an object $X$ is $3$ meters long what this actually means is that if I take a ruler that is known to be $1$ meter long and use it to measure the length of $3$ then I have to use my ruler exactly $3$ times. Said another way, if I had three copies of my ruler and I stacked them end-to-end, I'd get something of the same length as $X$.
This is, as far as I know, the way the Greeks understood length (so you can see why irrational lengths like the diagonal of a square might have bothered them; an irrational length, or more precisely an irrational ratio of lengths, cannot be understood in this way). One way to say it is that the number $3$ (for example) is not a length but an operator on lengths: it is the operator "multiply a length by $3$," or in more concrete terms the operator "use a ruler $3$ times" or "make $3$ copies of this ruler and stack them end-to-end." Equivalently you can think of this as describing a relationship between lengths (namely, the relationship of being $3$ times as long).
This idea can be used to make sense of all the non-negative real numbers. To get negative numbers into the game we can, for example, think in terms of operations on $1$-dimensional vectors (so $-1$ is the reflection through the origin), and to get complex numbers into the game we think in terms of operations on $2$-dimensional vectors (so $i$ is rotation by $90^{\circ}$, as you say). This point of view makes it very natural to graduate from the complex numbers to matrices, differential operators, and so on and so forth, which are all also operators acting on higher-dimensional spaces. When restricted to the natural numbers it is also closely related to defining the natural numbers as Church numerals.

I like the ruler example, it seems the distinction between operator and number isn't so clear cut. Irrational numbers seem to fall somewhere else on this spectrum as well.

@Livid: at some point if you think exclusively in terms of real physical lengths you run into the issue that lengths simply cannot be measured to infinite precision, in fact they can't really be measured to precision finer than the Planck length (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units). So there's a strong case to be made that none of the real numbers that arise in physics (for example) are really real numbers but that this is a convenient idealization we use to ignore this issue about precision. This question of rationality vs. irrationality is an infinite precision issue only.

That is also very interesting. Actually how I got to the thought in the OP was considering that probabilities were originally defined combinatorically as favored/total possible configurations (ie, limited to rational numbers between 0-1). Nowadays irrational numbers are "allowed" while negative and imaginary are not. It seems to me we need some justification to allow some of these numbers but not others.

@Livid: that's actually not true; in fact quantum mechanics requires you to deal with complex probabilities, in some sense, although they're called amplitudes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_amplitude).

They are discussed in niche cases of course: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_probability But no one will bat an eye at p = 2/pi while if you say p = -0.25 a philosophical argument will ensue (and code will break/error).

Why not both? Why not go further?
I'm not sure how much you know about, say, groups/rings/lattices. But, taking rings as an example, a ring is typically defined as a set with two operations, $\oplus$ and $\otimes$, that behave "like numbers should" in some sense:

$\oplus$ is associative and commutative. It has an identity, $\mathbf{0}$, and each element has an $\oplus$-wise inverse.
$\otimes$ is associative and has an identity, $\mathbf{1}$.
$\otimes$ distributes over $\oplus$: that is, $a\otimes(b\oplus c) = (a\otimes b) \oplus (a \otimes c)$, and also $(b\oplus c)\otimes a = (b\otimes a)\oplus(c\otimes a)$. (We have to specify both directions here because $\otimes$ isn't commutative.)

The real numbers form a ring, but so do "the set of all $3\times 3$ matrices", and "the integers mod 12" - so rings are useful to study in general.
And we also study what happens if we loosen some of these restrictions: we could drop $\oplus$-wise inverses to get a semiring, or drop $\otimes$ entirely to get an Abelian group... There are all sorts of similar generalizations of common structures that have a vast, deep theory behind them.
In universal algebra, we study algebraic structures in general. We consider sets equipped with any number of operations, and allow the operations to have any 'arity' (that is, how many inputs they accept). Then we can define a set of equations saying how the operations interact.
But there's a restriction on those equations: all variables must quantify over all elements of the algebra. This means we can't make 'existence' statements. But despite this, we can still express the conditions to be a ring in this framework!
We'd say something like:

There are two 2-ary operations ($\oplus$ and $\otimes$), one 1-ary operation (${\sim}\square$), and two 0-ary operations ($\mathbf{0}$ and $\mathbf{1}$), such that the following equations always hold:

$x\oplus y = y\oplus x$
$x\oplus (y \oplus z) = (x \oplus y) \oplus z$
$x\oplus  {\sim}x = \mathbf{0}$
$x\otimes (y \otimes z) = (x \otimes y) \otimes z$
$x\otimes \mathbf{1} = x$
$\mathbf{1} \otimes x = x$
$x\otimes(y\oplus z) = (x\otimes y) \oplus (x \otimes z)$
$(x\oplus y)\otimes z = (x\otimes z)\oplus(y\otimes z)$


So now, exactly as you wanted, negation is a fundamental unary operation... but moreover, the 'constants' 0 and 1 are just zeroary operations!

One could also not work within the framework of universal algebra, but instead define $\sum$ and $\prod$ as operations with an indefinite arity - they can take any amount of numbers. So you can write, say, $\sum(1,2,3,4) = 10$. (To formalize this, you'd probably want to say they operate on sequences or multisets.)
Here, negation would be defined as a separate unary operator. But, 0 and 1 "fall out of" addition and multiplication: $\sum() = 0$ and $\prod() = 1$!
This would be an unbiased definition, and similar definitions have some nice advantages - they make lots of statements and definitions cleaner (about, e.g., primality, or connectivity of topological spaces).

Unfortunately I don't know much about rings/etc. It became too much new jargon for me to parse. But if I get your point the is some level at which operator vs number is a choice, and other aspects of the system can be adjusted to output the same behavior either way.

@Livid Basically, a ring is a "number system" of a certain type. It has to have an 'addition-like' operation and a 'multiplication-like' operation, and they should interact as we expect. It also needs to have a '0-like' element that does nothing when you add it, and a '1-like' element that does nothing when you multiply it. Our familiar numbers form a ring, of course, but there are many other rings as well. (If you've seen 2x2 matrices, for instance, they form a ring; the '0-like' object is the zero matrix, and the '1-like' object is the identity matrix.)

The point of me mentioning all this is that you can define the necessary conditions for a ring by just talking about operations of different arities. The 'addition' and 'multiplication' are binary operators, of course. Negation becomes a fundamental unary operator, exactly as you wanted - your @. But then '0' and '1' are zero-ary operators! (And the actual number -1 'falls out of' negation and 1.)

This is just an alternate way of stating the same rules, but this alternate perspective is useful when we start studying what happens when we change the rules - maybe we add or remove operators, and see what results we get.
